# Properly aligned appendix in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm trying to write my own class and while I'm didn't use `hyperref` package following code work properly.

```
\newcommand\chaptindent{\advance\leftskip 1.0em \hskip -\leftskip}
\newcommand\appenindent{\advance\leftskip 6.0em \hskip -\leftskip}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne
    \if@mainmatter                 
       \refstepcounter{chapter}%
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
           {\chaptindent\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
    \else
       \refstepcounter{chapter}
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
           {\appenindent\nobreak\@chapapp\space\protect\numberline{
                \thechapter}\space{#1}}
    \fi
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
  \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading}
```

[image]

After I had include `hyperref` package the appendix ToC lines moved over left border.
[image]

Removed `\chaptindent` and `\appenindent` from `\@chapter` redifinition and got ToC without any standoff
[image]

Try to fix this issue with `\def\l@chapter{\@dottedtocline{1}{0.0em}{1.0em}}` command but there are the same indent for chapter and appendix lines.
[image]

How can I get Properly ToC appendix aligned with using `hyperref` package?

Comment: This is difficult to tell. At which point do you load the `hyperref` package? It does redefinitions of the structure level macros

Comment: At the beginning of class. Where all others packages were included with `\RequirePackage` command.

Comment: Try to load it at the end of the class with `\AtEndOfClass` or better, do not load it automatically

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: 'Didn't work' is no useful description.

Comment: The end of the class `hyperref` loading works as `\RequirePackage{hyperref}` at the beginning of class

Comment: You shouldn't do the formatting in `\addcontentsline` (hyperref changes it). Beside this you have quite a number of spurious spaces in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem. So there is solution which may be useful for someone.
Appendices are the same chapters and, so for showing them in table of contents uses same
command as for chapters and it's `\l@chapter`. This command is formed while `\contentsline{chapter}{...` 
items handling.For differentiate chapters and appendices needs to form different `\contentsline` items in
.toc file, as follow `\contentsline{chapter}{...` and `\contentsline{appendix}{...`. For handling
`\contentsline{appendix}{...` it have been needed to implement `\l@appendix` command. After this I got
opportunity to separate handling for chapters and appendices whereas table of contents is forming.

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne%
                    \if@mainmatter%                 
                      \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline\thechapter\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}%
                    \else%
                      \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                      \phantomsection
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}%
    {\texorpdfstring{\@chapapp\space\protect\numberline\thechapter\space#1}
     {\@chapapp\space\thechapter\space#1}}%
                    \fi%
                    \else%
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi%
                      \chaptermark{#1}%
                      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                      \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading}
```

So this code generate following .toc file content

```
...
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline 2\MakeUppercase {\IeC ...
...
\contentsline {appendix}{{\Ukrainian \CYRD ...
```

which is handled by two commands

```
\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{%
   \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip 0.0em\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg plus 15em \parfillskip -
  \rightskip%mod <plus 15em> for avoid hyph. in TOC
     \parindent 0.0em\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima 1.0em\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#1}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
      \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
         mu$}\hfill
      \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil \normalcolor #2}%   \hfil\normalfont   |||
    \par}%
   \fi}

\newcommand\l@appendix[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip 0.0em\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg plus 15em \parfillskip -
 \rightskip%mod <plus 15em> for avoid hyph. in TOC
     \parindent 0.0em\relax \hangindent 4.3em\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima 1.5em\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#1}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
       mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil \normalcolor #2}%   \hfil\normalfont   |||
     \par}%
  \fi}
```

`\phantomsection` used for `hyperref` links works correct.
[image]